# Android cache heavy object for fragment

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity

Where is the best place to cache a heavy object (long initiation time) to not build each time when I enter the fragment. I'm thinking to keep it in Activity and pass each time when fragment is initialized. Does it sound sensible? Is there any good pattern for that?

Comment: What is type of the heavy object? You can use LruCache to cache Big object like bitmap and use a global manager of that.

Comment: no, the object takes a lots of things from DB and does some extra calculation. The computing time is around 5 seconds. Can't do it each time when enter the fragment

Answer (score 0):

**Does it sound sensible?**

Yes it is sensible if same object shares its properties with different fragments and/or locations.

**Is there any good pattern for that?**

I can't recall any specific pattern for given scenario but there is a good practice to coomunicate between `Activity` and `Fragment`. Have a look at [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

> no, the object takes a lots of things from DB and does some extra calculation. The computing time is around 5 seconds. Can't do it each time when enter the fragment

Too litle info to fully answer your question. Still, it may be sufficient to just cache the result of your computation and show it on subsequent use, while for the first time it may be acceptable to even block the UI, show "Please wait. Calculating" for that 5 secs. Or, perhaps better from user perspective spawn background thread which either reads cached value or does the computation and once that phase is done, notifies (i.e. using event bus, rxjava or even broadcast) fragment to update itself with privided calculation results